# Loading bar with execution time from server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

In my website, I use a script (on server) with data sent from the webpage. The problem is that the script execution time (+data transit) takes 5 to 30 seconds to execute and waiting can be quite long for the user so I was wondering what is the best way to create a waiting loading bar? Do I have to execute a first function on the server that will calculate the time, and then send it to the client, or do I use repeted AJAX requests with each time, the current status ?

The advantage with the second one is that it's easier to just send the status after each part of the script than to calculate the speed from just the data sent. Moreover it could be more precise, basing itself on the actual connection time... But I think it could use more server ressources. And if I choose that what is the best delay between each requests ?

Thank you for your answers

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! as is stands, your question looks too broad to get a single correct answer - you might want to take a look at [What type of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). If you have a more specific question, I would give it another go - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for what sort of questions to ask.

Comment: See here please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43819354/connection-stream x)