# Connection stream

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Is there another way to create a connection stream between a loaded page (client) and the server without using repeated AJAX calls, like every half second? I think of something that will make the client listening until the server gives a response (which can take a few seconds to arrive).

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Try exploring Sockets and Web workers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to recommd you Phil Leggetter's [Guide to Real-time technologies](https://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide/) - because that is what you are looking for.

You will need one of the html5 introduced connection aspects: WebSockets, Server-Sent Events or even WebRTC DataChannel could be possible if you have a peer-to-peer use case.

In reference to the above link, its always about your server setup and your use case - that in mind some commonly used technologies would be: [Pusher](https://pusher.com/), [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/), [Socket.io](https://socket.io/), [Ratchet](http://socketo.me), etc.

---

**Update**

Server-sent-events do have more server-side compatibilitly, technically it is more like optimized HTTP streaming, you can read more details in the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#eventsource-push) and on [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/%5C#feat=eventsource). 
If you need a constant bidirectional connection and better client side support you better go with [WebSockets](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets). But you will need to set up a compatible server or use an external service like Pusher or Firebase.

Comment: What is exactly the difference between WebSockets and Server-Sent Events ? Because it looks like both can do what I want but Server-Sent events seems to have more browsers compatibility so...

Comment: I have attachted you some links in the update of my answer.

Comment: Looks like server sent events seems more easy to set and are enough for what I want. And thanks for making me discover something I really didn't know about

Comment: My pleasure, just try it out. But be aware that SSE are not yet supported in Edge and IE. You will have to use some fallbacks like ajax polling if you choose to use SSE.